# How to change the style of Title attribute inside the <area> tag?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions, css-animations

How do I change the "title" attribute on hover effect.
Is CSS can't change the tooltip appearance. It is browser/OS-dependent.??

Comment: mention what you tried..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please post code what have you tried.